# how to find target path of link if the file is a link file

Tags: python, file, hyperlink

how to find if the file is a link file, and find the path of the target file (actual file pointed by the link file)

Comment: how many times do you have to be given link to the same page?

Answer (score 33):

[`os.path.islink`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.islink) (is it a link?) and [`os.path.realpath`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath) (get ultimate pointed to path, regardless of whether it's a link).

If `os.path.islink` is True, and you only want to follow the first link, use [`os.readlink`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.readlink).

Comment: os.path.realpath doesnot give the path of the actual target file's path as said.

Comment: Looks like `os.path.realpath` does resolve symbolic links, including multiply-linked (multiply-nested?) symlinks.

Comment: os.path.realpath does resolve the links only in Unix systems, not Windows.

Comment: `os.path.realpath` is not correctly resolving the link target in Python 2.3 on Linux

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.lstat()`, then inspect the `st_mode` field.